# Setting work directory in gradle for liquibase plugin?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, liquibase, gradle-plugin

So I'm migrating from Maven to Gradle and I've run into a bit of a snag.  It's a multi-project build with one of the sub-projects being a liquibase migration.  I've successfully moved it to Gradle, but the initial changeset has references to other changesets in a "relative" path form, for example:

*changeset-master.xml*

```
...
 <include file="src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog-1.xml"/>
 <include file="src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog-2.xml"/>
 <include file="src/main/resources/changelogs/changelog-3.xml"/>
...
```

I've tried using variable substitution in the `changelog-master.xml` file using `${}` properties, but no luck.  Right now I have the liquibase scripts being run separately, but I'd like to have them invoked as part of the main build if possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do include with relative paths the `relativeToChangelogFile` can help you.

```
...
 <include file="changelog-1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="changelog-2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 <include file="changelog-3.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
...
```